# JavaScript called from Div onclick running button.click call

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a Div onclick function that calls the JavaScript function below

```
function MonthViewDay(sDate){
        var txtHidden = document.getElementById('<%=txtHidden.ClientID %>');
        var btn_Hidden = document.getElementById('<%= btn_Hidden.ClientID %>');

        if (txtHidden !== null) {
            txtHidden.innerText = sDate;
        } else{
            alert("Control '<%=txtHidden.ClientID %>' not found.");
        }

        if (btn_Hidden !== null) {
            btn_Hidden.click;
        } else {
            alert("Control '<%= btn_Hidden.ClientID %>' not found.");
        }

    }
```

The problem I am getting is that the btn_Hidden.click is not firing, but the txtHidden text is being update, but the btn_Hidden.click is not firing.

As you can see from my sample, I have a 'test' in place to see if the btn control is found and it is, as far as I can see.

Troubleshooting steps I have taken are,

- Removing the txtbox section, no help.
- Recreating the button on the aspx page, no help.
- Physically click the button, click event fires.
- Inserting `document.getElementById('<%= btn_Hidden.ClientID %>').click` instead of btn_Hidden.click, no help.

Please assist.

Thank you in advance

Rhys

Comment: You're talking about JavaScript not Java. They are totally different.

Comment: Point taken, sorry, thanx for updating the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Click** is a method not a field in javascript

Simulate a mouse-click use  `.click()`;

In your code use

```
  btn_Hidden.click();
```

Comment: Oh for flying snakes, that worked.  Thank you Pragnani.